# how to use an ajax to change the input value in celleditor

Tags: ajax, primefaces, tablecelleditor

Am trying to add a `<p:ajax>` to my `<p:inputText>` to change the initial number in my input in cell editor PrimeFaces and I want the input to display in the `h:outputText`

my bean

```
public void onValuechange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    Object oldValue =  event.getOldValue();
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
    if (newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue))
        quantity = (int) newValue; 
}
```

my xhtml

```
<p:column id="tmp" headerText="Quantity Requested(click to edit)" style="width: 150px; text-align: center" >
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output"> 
            <h:outputText value="#{openJob.quantity}" id="output" />  
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">  
            <h:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{openJob.quantity}" style="width:96%">
                <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{openJob.onValuechange}" immediate="true" resetValues="true" disabled="false" execute="modelIput" render="output" />
            </h:inputText> 
        </f:facet> 
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

Comment: `public void on Value change(Value Change Event event) {` and the rest of your bean is completely invalid java. Please, please, please be careful. and please create a [mcve]. And it is PrimeFaces, not prime-faces

Comment: Oh and you add an `f:ajax` to a `h:inputText`, not the `p:` ones like you state in your text. And please clarify what the problem is, investigate what **does** go on etc...

Comment: am new in stackoverflow so i don't know how to input my code that is why you saw the code like that, can you please help me out with my question

Comment: There is an example in the PF showcase. Get that to work and you have an answer to your (unclear) problem)